# Arithmetic Error When Converting String to Double

Tags: c++, string, double

I'm writing a function to convert a user provided string into a double. It works quite well for certain values, but fails for others. For example

```
string_to_double("123.45") = 123.45
string_to_double(12345) = 12345
```

but

```
string_to_double(123.4567) = 123.457
```

I'm fairly certain that this is some kind of round off error, but I'm not using approximations nor am I using very small or large values. My question is two-fold why am I getting these strange results and how can I change my code to get more accurate results? I'm also doing this as a personal challenge, so suggestions to use methods such as `std::stod` are not helpful. I believe the problem occurs in the second for-loop, but I felt it was wise to include the entire method because if I missed something it isn't that much extra code to read.

**My Code**

```
template <class T>
double numerical_descriptive_measures<T>::string_to_double(std::string user_input)
{
    double numeric_value = 0;//Stores numeric value of string. Return value.
    int user_input_size = user_input.size();
    int power = 0;
    /*This loop is for the characteristic portion of the input
    once this loop finishes, we know what to multiply the
    characterstic portion by(e.g. 1234 = 1*10^3 + 2*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 4)
    */
    for(int i = 0;i < user_input_size;i++)
    {
        if(user_input[i] == '.')
            break;
        else
            power++;
    }
    /*This loop is for the mantissa. If this portion is zero, 
    the loop doesn't execute because i will be greater than
    user_input_size.*/
    for(int i = 0;i < user_input_size;i++)
    {
        if(user_input[i] != '.')
        {
            numeric_value += ((double)user_input[i] - 48.0)*pow(10,power-i-1);
        }
        else
        {
            double power = -1.0;
            for(int j = i+1;j < user_input_size;j++)
            {
                numeric_value += ((double)user_input[j] - 48.0)*pow(10.0,power);
                power = power-1.0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return numeric_value;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the value is really  123.457?  How are you printing it?  Probably the printing function is just rounding it.  Also, why are you reinventing this wheel?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm printing the function using std::cout<<data<<std::endl. This problem arouse from a statistics class I'm writing. I'm just a lowly student at this point, so the more code I have under my belt, the better. This came up for input testing (making sure no one submits any goofy values such as "find the average of abc").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that you are producing the wrong floating point value, the problem is that you are printing it with insufficient precision:

```
std::cout<<data<<std::endl
```

This will only print about six digits of precision.   You can use [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) or other methods to print more.

Comment: The code WILL produce incorrect values in general though -- see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not producing an incorrect value for "123.4567" but it will produce incorrect values in general. For example, string_to_double("0.0012") produces (on Visual Studio 2015)

0.0012000000000000001117161918529063768801279366016387939453125

but the correct answer is

0.00119999999999999989487575735580549007863737642765045166015625

(You would have to print them to 17 significant digits to tell the difference.)

The problem is that you can't use floating-point to convert to floating-point -- it does not have enough precision in general.

(I've written a lot about this on my site; for example, see http://www.exploringbinary.com/quick-and-dirty-decimal-to-floating-point-conversion/ and http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-to-floating-point-needs-arbitrary-precision/ .)